# Load and use BoostedTreesClassifier saved model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to use a BoostedTreesClassifier saved model in TensorFlow but I can't figure out how to use the loaded model to make predictions. I'm using the sample code from the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/boosted_trees) here. This is the minimal code I'm working with:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

tf.random.set_seed(123)

dftrain = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')
dfeval = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv')
y_train = dftrain.pop('survived')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('survived')

CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['sex', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'class', 'deck',
                       'embark_town', 'alone']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['age', 'fare']

def one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocab):
  return tf.feature_column.indicator_column(
      tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name,
                                                 vocab))
feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  # Need to one-hot encode categorical features.
  vocabulary = dftrain[feature_name].unique()
  feature_columns.append(one_hot_cat_column(feature_name, vocabulary))

for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name,
                                           dtype=tf.float32))

NUM_EXAMPLES = len(y_train)

def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  def input_fn():
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
    if shuffle:
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(NUM_EXAMPLES)
    # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).
    dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)
    # In memory training doesn't use batching.
    dataset = dataset.batch(NUM_EXAMPLES)
    return dataset
  return input_fn

train_input_fn = make_input_fn(dftrain, y_train)
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(dfeval, y_eval, shuffle=False, n_epochs=1)

n_batches = 1
est = tf.estimator.BoostedTreesClassifier(feature_columns,
                                          n_batches_per_layer=n_batches)

est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)

result = est.evaluate(eval_input_fn)

# Make predictions
pred_dicts = list(est.predict(eval_input_fn))
probs = pd.Series([pred['probabilities'][1] for pred in pred_dicts])

probs.plot(kind='hist', bins=20, title='predicted probabilities')
plt.show()

# Save model
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
serving_input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
saved_model_path = est.export_saved_model('saved_model', serving_input_receiver_fn)

# Load model
loaded_est = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_path)

# How can I use loaded_est to make predictions?
# pred_dicts_using_loaded_model = list(loaded_est.predict(eval_input_fn))
# probs_using_loaded_model = pd.Series([pred['probabilities'][1] for pred in pred_dicts_using_loaded_model])
```

**Edit:** The last two commented lines are just to show what I ultimately would like to achieve. They will not run correctly nor are they meant to because `loaded_est` is a different kind of object than `est`. I don't know how I can use `loaded_est` to make predictions as I would with `est`. I have looked at the documentation for saving and loading models [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) where they do it on an image but I couldn't transpose that to this data, where the input would just be a vector (i.e. a row from the `dfeval` DataFrame).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding example code on [medium.com](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/save-and-load-a-tensorflow-estimator-model-for-predictions-233b798620a9) contributed by Ajeet Singh by searching for [something slightly more generic](https://www.google.com/search?q=save%20and%20load%20tensorflow%20estimator). To answer my own question, here is the code to make predictions using the loaded model:

```
def predict(loaded_model, row, columns, dtypes):
  example = tf.train.Example()
  for i in range(len(columns)):
    if dtypes[i] == 'object':
      example.features.feature[columns[i]].bytes_list.value.extend([bytes(row[i], 'utf-8')])
    elif dtypes[i] == 'float':
      example.features.feature[columns[i]].float_list.value.extend([row[i]])
    elif dtypes[i] == 'int64':
      example.features.feature[columns[i]].int64_list.value.extend([row[i]])
  return loaded_model.signatures['predict'](examples=tf.constant([example.SerializeToString()]))

pred_dicts_using_loaded_model = [predict(loaded_est, row, dfeval.columns, dfeval.dtypes) for row in dfeval.itertuples(index=False)]
probs_using_loaded_model = [pred_dict['probabilities'][0][1].numpy() for pred_dict in pred_dicts_using_loaded_model]

for p in zip(probs, probs_using_loaded_model):
  print(p)
```